# With a Jenkins multi-configuration build, how do I retrigger one particular configuration?

Tags: jenkins

I have a large and time-consuming multi-configuration build, and once in a while I want to re-trigger only one of the configurations. How can I easily do that? I'd like it to still be easy to see that that all configurations have passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Matrix Reloaded plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Reloaded+Plugin)

This gives you an interactive way of rerunning combinations

> On all Matrix builds that has run while the plugin was installed there
>   will be a Matrix reloaded link. Click this, and it will take you to a
>   dialog, where you can check-mark the configurations that should be
>   build again. Nothing is checked by default, but the check-marks you
>   set will be cascaded as default settings, if applicable, to any
>   down-stream jobs triggered by the re-run.